# Magento CDN http or https

Tags: php, server, magento-1.9, cdn

Recently i configured cdn to my magento store but after that some images doesn't show after upload every time i try to upload image from the back-end its still

```
media/tmp/catalaog/
```

but when i save the new product the image URL is now like this

```
media/catalog/
```

and the image doesn't exist now or it wasn't move from tmp. My site is in https should i install ssl to my cdn too?

Answer (score 0):

If your https page have any http resources included, you will run into mixed content, so yes you need to make your images load over https.

> To fix this type of error, all requests to HTTP content should be
>   removed and replaced with content served over HTTPS. Some common
>   examples of mixed content include JavaScript files, stylesheets,
>   images, videos, and other media.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/Mixed_content